# Distinct with select *

Tags: sql

Is it possible to use select * with distinct or write easily something that has the same impact?

I need to select all columns from a table with distinct value, but listing all the columns in select clause would be nerve-breaking because the number of columns is over 20!

Comment: Does your table not have a primary key? How have you got duplicate rows?

Comment: Over 20? Bah! When I was young, we had to manually list tables that had 100s of columns, in the snow, barefoot, uphill both ways. Seriously: is that really so horrible? Most modern IDEs have a way to dump the column names, and more importantly, you'd only have to write this out a few times. (Also, debugging a `SELECT *` query that breaks related functionality because someone else added a column is not pretty.)

Comment: Maybe it's not THAT horrible, but as far as I know, the purpose of computing is to make things easier...and what I have learned, if you write dozens of lines for a simple task, if is likely that there is an easier way! :D

Answer (score 7):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can write:

```
select distinct * from MyTable
```

However, it is considered "best practice" to specify the columns explicitly, partly because it improves the performance of the query, but also to protect yourself from failures that would arise if the database schema were to change in the future

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee, Rank
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "distinct" keyword right after "select" does the work.
For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```